# Can't edit hunk when adding patch

Tags: git, ubuntu, wsl-2, neovim

I am running Ubuntu via WSL2.

No issue when using nvim in general.

However when running `git add --all -p`, then asking to edit a patch, I get an error message: `nvim: 1: nvim: Permission denied`

I suspect that when running this command, `git` tries to run `nvim` in a subprocess using a user that can't access/run `nvim`. I have no idea how to [in]validate this hypothesis and/or how to fix it. Never had this issue before.

The full view:

```
❯❯ ~/code/startpressuring git:(25-create-campaign)
❯ git aa -p package.json
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 5be88af..cd81744 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -27,6 +27,13 @@
         "vue-loader": "^16.1.2"
     },
     "dependencies": {
-        "@headlessui/vue": "^1.2.0"
+        "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
+        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.14.5",
+        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
+        "@headlessui/vue": "^1.2.0",
+        "@tiptap/core": "^2.0.0-beta.93",
+        "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.0.0-beta.89",
+        "@tiptap/vue-3": "^2.0.0-beta.48",
+        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2"
     }
 }
(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]? e
nvim: 1: nvim: Permission denied
@@ -27,6 +27,13 @@
         "vue-loader": "^16.1.2"
     },
     "dependencies": {
-        "@headlessui/vue": "^1.2.0"
+        "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
+        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.14.5",
+        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
+        "@headlessui/vue": "^1.2.0",
+        "@tiptap/core": "^2.0.0-beta.93",
+        "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.0.0-beta.89",
+        "@tiptap/vue-3": "^2.0.0-beta.48",
+        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2"
     }
 }
(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]?
```

**EDIT**
Well, somehow, in the process, I removed neovim.appimage and installed it via apt out of curiosity and I don't have the bug anymore.

Comment: Git itself never does anything fancy with setuid or permissions, it just runs OS commands the easy way. The `nvim: 1:` output is particularly weird because it suggests you've run a *shell* named `nvim`, and that's trying to run something else named `nvim`. Note that `git add -p` is implemented as a perl script, which you can run (a copy of) directly, inserting debug prints to see what's going on.

Comment: Well, somehow, in the process, I removed neovim.appimage and installed it via apt out of curiosity and I don't have the bug anymore.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.  Don't forget to mark the question as closed!  Usually I might recommend a self-answer, but (a) it doesn't seem like enough for an answer, and (b) this really is off-topic for Stack Overflow anyway.  It's more a *configuration* issue, so probably better for [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been solved but not in a way that is enough to call it an answer.